# Mono.Cecil - Getting TypeReference from System.Type

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

Is there possible to get `TypeReference` or `TypeDefinition` of type assigned to `System.Type` variable?

To be more concrete, I'm trying to get `String` type from following definition of attribute:

```
Custom(Value=typeof(String))]
        public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use *ModuleDefinition.ImportReference()*:

```
var a = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
var type = typeof(string);
var tr = a.MainModule.ImportReference(type);
var td = tr.Resolve();
Console.WriteLine($"tr = {tr}\ntd = {td}");
```